# How can I do a search in my contactsContract with setOnQueryTextListener in ListFragment?

Tags: android, searchview, loader

I have a ListFragment that to a request of my ContactsContract and display the contacts in the fragment with  LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks. I've developed the function to do a search with the action bar. I can see this new feature and it works, but I'm not sure how implementing the code to do that works and do the search in my contacts:

All help will be apreciate:

This is the code what I have to show the search in the action bar.

```
@Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu (Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_search, menu);
        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        final SearchView sv = new SearchView(((MainActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().getThemedContext());
        MenuItemCompat.setShowAsAction(item, MenuItemCompat.SHOW_AS_ACTION_COLLAPSE_ACTION_VIEW | MenuItemCompat.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);
        MenuItemCompat.setActionView(item, sv);

        sv.setQueryHint(getString(R.string.type_search));
        sv.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
        sv.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Submitted: "+query, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "tap: "+newText, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return false;
            }
        });
super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu,inflater);
}
```

Comment: check this link. Maybe help for your problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38265238/how-can-i-do-a-search-in-my-contactscontract-with-setonquerytextlistener-in-list